# Where do you set keywords for applications in order to get them to show up in software center and dash searches?

Tags: software-center, application-development, unity-dash

Exactly as the title states, what fields do you modify in order to return an app for specific search terms in dash and software-center?

Is it keywords in the applications .desktop file?
Something in the debian packaging files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Recognized desktop entry keys](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys) you would use the `Keywords` key in the .desktop file for the application.